# I am not able to create ScrollView in android studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, scrollview

I wish to create Scrollview with linear layout which will have textview in it (in Android Studio). But my scrollview doesn't work. And I am also not able to add Text more that AVD screen dimension. My XML code is below:-

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="723dp"
                android:padding="25dp"
                android:text="@string/textview"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`



I expect my Android app to have scrollview with linearlayout and with Textview showing lengthy text which can be scrolled vertically
```

Answer (score 0):

*Used this code*

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Rahul"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Rahul"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Rahul"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Rahul"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Rahul"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Rahul"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Rahul"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Rahul"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Rahul"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Rahul"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Rahul"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Rahul"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Rahul"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Rahul"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Rahul"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```